# 2 tables join: Impressions count before Conversion

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I actually have no idea on how perform such a query.
I have 2 tables in my Google BigQuery:

First table (Impressions):

```
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
| Timestamp | UserID | Event_Type | Count |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
|       100 |    111 | impression |     2 |
|       105 |    111 | impression |     1 |
|       110 |    111 | impression |     1 |
|       120 |    111 | impression |     2 |
|       100 |    222 | impression |     1 |
|       105 |    222 | impression |     1 |
|       110 |    222 | impression |     1 |
|       120 |    222 | impression |     1 |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Second table (Conversions):

```
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
| Timestamp | UserID | Event_Type | Count |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
|       115 |    111 | conversion |     1 |
|       117 |    222 | conversion |     1 |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
```

What I want to get - Number of Impressions per User needed for Conversion, so I ahve to count all the Impressions that happened before the conversion (by timestamp - it is in unix format actually).

```
+--------+--------------------+
| UserID | Impressions Needed |
+--------+--------------------+
|    111 |                  4 |
|    222 |                  3 |
+--------+--------------------+
```

I can JOIN these tables by UserID and get total number of Impression and Conversions, I can union them and sort by UserID and Timestamp, but I have no idea how to get the final answer so unfortunately I have nothing to show here. I hope there is a way to do this and someone here can help me with that.

The answer is (standard SQL):

``` SELECT t2.User_ID, COUNT(t1.User_ID) as ImpressionsNeeded
FROM
(
SELECT MIN(Event_Time) as Event_Time, User_ID, Advertiser_ID, Campaign_ID, count(*) AS Conv_Count
FROM ``db.dcm_account111111.activity_111111_*``
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170110' AND Advertiser_ID = '888888' AND Campaign_ID = '888888' AND Event_Sub_Type = 'POSTCLICK'
GROUP BY User_ID, Advertiser_ID, Campaign_ID
) as t2
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT Event_Time, User_ID, Advertiser_ID, Campaign_ID, count(*) AS Imps_Count
FROM ``db.dcm_account111111.impression_111111_*``
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170110' AND Advertiser_ID = '888888' AND Campaign_ID = '888888'
GROUP BY Event_Time, User_ID, Advertiser_ID, Campaign_ID
) as t1
ON t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID AND t1.Advertiser_ID = t2.Advertiser_ID AND t1.Campaign_ID = t2.campaign_ID AND t1.Event_Time < t2.Event_Time
GROUP BY t2.User_ID
ORDER BY ImpressionsNeeded DESC ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select t2.userid, count(t1.userid)
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.userid = t2.userid and
        t1.event_type = 'impression' and
        t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
group by t2.userid;
```

Comment: I have added the sample code above (used your answer, but it didn't work)

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya . . . Switch to standard SQL.

Comment: I have "Use legacy SQL" checkbox checked

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya . . . Uncheck that box.

Comment: It seems to be working now. However I get a user_id 'AMsySZbs1sNtG7tCkB942LhR8B1y' with 3146 impressions in front. When I'm just quering COUNT for that user_id from impressions table (same date range) I'm getting 255.

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya . . . That would be a problem with your subqueries.  You are probably missing a `JOIN` conditions between the subqueries.

Comment: I'm getting 8670 in front of specific User_ID after all that LEFT JOIN.
What I have found: if query COUNT from Conversion table for that User_ID - I get 34
if I query COUNT from Impression table for that User_ID - I get 255
255 * 34 = 8670
so for some reason COUNT from Impression table gets multiplied by the COUNT from Conversion table after JOIN

Comment: OK I got it. Since Conversion table has multiple rows for the same User_ID my results were multiplied. So i had to use MIN while querying Conversion table and only then LEFT JOIN Impression table. Thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

Below covers more generic cases, when you can identify how many Impressions lead to each & every Conversion (not just to very first one)
Additional benefit - no any *explicit* JOINs and GROUP BY

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH all_events AS (
  SELECT ts, UserID, Event_Type, cnt FROM Impressions UNION ALL
  SELECT ts, UserID, Event_Type, cnt FROM Conversions
)
SELECT ts as ConversionTS, UserID, cum_sum - 
  IFNULL(
    SUM(cum_sum) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, Event_Type ORDER BY ts 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0
  ) AS Impressions
FROM (
  SELECT ts, UserID, Event_Type, 
    SUM(IF(Event_Type = 'impression', cnt, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID 
      ORDER BY ts) AS cum_sum
  FROM all_events
)
WHERE Event_Type = 'conversion'
```

Above can be tested with below data (as an example)

```sql
WITH Impressions AS (
  SELECT 100 AS ts, 111 AS UserID, 'impression' AS Event_Type, 2 AS cnt UNION ALL SELECT 105, 111, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 110, 111, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 120, 111, 'impression', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 123, 111, 'impression', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 125, 111, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 130, 111, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 140, 111, 'impression', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 100, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 105, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 110, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 120, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 130, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 135, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 140, 222, 'impression', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 150, 222, 'impression', 1 
),
Conversions AS (
  SELECT 115 AS ts, 111 AS UserID, 'conversion' AS Event_Type, 1 AS cnt UNION ALL
  SELECT 135, 111, 'conversion', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 117, 222, 'conversion', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 147, 222, 'conversion', 1 
)
```

Expected result is as below

```sql
ConversionTS    UserID  Impressions  
115             111     4    
135             111     6    
117             222     3    
147             222     4
```

Answer (score -1):

OK I got it. Since Conversion table has multiple rows for the same User_ID my results were multiplied. So i had to use MIN while querying Conversion table and only then LEFT JOIN Impression table.
Fixed the code above.
Thank you Gordon!

Comment: This site works by marking the answer that answered your question and the answer, not by adding your own comment as an answer. I'd recommend removing this and ticking  @Gordons answer to mark it as correct.